# rails routes locale, gem 'route_translator' or gem 'i18n_routing' unable to translate match in resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, routes, i18n-gem

1. mainly i would use i18n_routing gem
   i will be happy if i will translate match 'vlk' under dashboard resource, trying everything around, and no success. Resources are translated successfully also new action...whats wrong?

routes.rb

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'home#index'

  localized do
    resources :cars
    resource :admin, :controller => :admin
      resource :dashboard do
        member do
          match 'vlk', :as => :vlk
        end
      end
    end
end
```

routes.yml

```
cs:
  cars: 'auta'
  admin: 'admincesky'
  routes:
    dashboard:
      as: 'novy'
      path_names:
        new: 'cesky_member'
        vlk: 'tzz_cesky'
      named_routes_path:
        vlk: 'tzz_cesky'
```

2.secondly, i tried next gem 'route_translator' and i cant get running 'route_translator' gem i am getting this error

```
/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.0.14/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route.rb:25:in `initialize': can't convert Array into String (TypeError)
```

if i add line at the end of routes.rb file

```
Dt::Application.routes.translate_from_file('config/locales/routes.yml')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I tried a lot - without any solution.

I tried this gem https://github.com/kwi/i18n_routing - that fixed my problems :-)